# Constructive non-constructive questions

Tags: discussion

For some time I encounter quite many questions, which follow very similar scenario: the question violates some SO rules, but actually is very helpful, receives many upvotes and favourites. Let the example be: [Good example of Reactive Extensions Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550763/good-example-of-reactive-extensions-use)

In summary, this is a question of type "give me example of...", which technically falls under "not constructive". But it has >40 score, which puts it in [0.4%](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/262663) that useful posts of the whole site.

The natural resolution to such question would be to ask someone to search in Google, but actually when you enter ["Example of Rx usage"](https://www.google.pl/search?q=Example+of+Rx+usage) in Google, this StackOverflow's question appears as a first result.

This is only a single example; I agree, that like 98% of "non-constructive"s are absolutely justified, but there are some exceptions, which are closed and prevent users to enter more information on that matter, but on the other hand are very useful and follow the general purpose of SO site: to provide useful knowledge.

What I'd suggest in this case would be some kind of exception mechanism, which would allow users (say, 5000+) to vote, such that this kind of questions - despite breaking SO's rules - are protected against closing and allow adding new answers.

This is of course a long-shot and very unlikely to happen; so my question is:
What is the proper way of dealing with such questions? Close them in accordance with SO rules, but actually against SO general purpose? Vote on reopening?

Comment: What about adding that accepted answer to the wiki of [tag:system.reactive] and delete the question? problem solved?

Comment: related: [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/162704)

Comment: @Yannis Lock seems to be a good solution... except that it prevents adding answers, comments and generally *more value* to that question. So locking actually differs very little from closing.

Comment: Locking is an alternative to deletion - which is the end result for most closed questions. It certainly isn't exactly what you are looking for, but if this discussion concludes that the question in question should be closed, then perhaps locking it to prevent deletion may make sense.

Comment: @Yannis sure, but generally the whole idea of my post is not only prevent deletion, but still allow adding value to the question. By rule of thumb you disallow modifications or adding answers to prevent corruption, damaging the post or further off-topic discussions. But if the question actually provides value (and upvotes and favourites are a clear proof, that it does), why do so?

Answer (score 6):

**If you provide an exception mechanism to closure what will happen is that people will pester the mods or Meta or other users to allow *their* question to be an exception.** We already have people regularly come to Meta all offended that their flat out request for an external resource was closed but one from 3 years ago was not. They point to the old question as some sort of exception. Little do they realize that nobody made an *exception* for the old one. (Rules change, and there's the issue of luck). If we formally allowed exceptions such requests would multiply **irrespective of merit**.

> What is the proper way of dealing with such questions?

Close them.

> Vote on reopening?

No.